# Fixing iPhone App in XCode Using Crash Report

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function in my app where every time the user hits a "Submit" button after an action, the game checks whether the action is an Achievement in Game Center. Recently, the app has been crashing for a few people with and without connectivity (all different iPhone models, iPad models and iOS systems). From the crash log it looks like that is where the issue lies:

```
Incident Identifier: E44706D0-6B10-44DD-BDB2-EDCD563011DC
CrashReporter Key:   7580fe38161bf461fc45c8e5c4c5ab07747756be
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         APPNAME [1417]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/9B7EAD6C9-4A1F-4A46-84DE-762EDED1A1BD/APPNAME.app/APPNA
Identifier:      APPNAME
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-11-08 23:40:52.926 -0500
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A525)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3b3c03e2 0x3b2fe000 + 795618
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a41995e 0x3a411000 + 35166
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3b3c0302 0x3b2fe000 + 795394
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3b3103e6 0x3b2fe000 + 74726
4   APPNAME                     0x000f9950 -[Gamer updateCurrentAchievements:] (Gamer.m:621)
5   APPNAME                     0x000f9698 -[Gamer checkWord] (Gamer.m:560)
6   APPNAME                     0x000f8d22 -[Gamer ButtonPressed:] (Gamer.m:394)
```

This is the block of code it is referring to:

```
-(void) updateCurrentAchievements:(int) achievement_number
{
NSLog(@"Achievement Number is %d",achievement_number);
char ch = [ self.appDelegate.previous_Achieved characterAtIndex:achievement_number-1 ];
if( ch == '0' )
{
    currentAchieved[self.appDelegate.new_Achievements] = achievement_number;
    self.appDelegate.new_Achievements++;
    NSLog(@"new achievements are : %d",self.appDelegate.new_Achievements);
    self.appDelegate.current_Achieved = [self.appDelegate.current_Achieved stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange((achievement_number-1), 1) withString:@"1"];
        self.appDelegate.previous_Achieved = self.appDelegate.current_Achieved;
        [self.appDelegate checkAchievements:achievement_number];
    }
    NSLog(@"current Achievement string is %@ and length is %d",self.appDelegate.current_Achieved,[self.appDelegate.current_Achieved length]);
}
```

Any ideas what might be going on here? Any insight is appreciated. I'm sorry if I didn't provide more info, but let me know and I can certainly fill you in more. Thank you!

Comment: not really the issue..but you really really shouldn't be using your appdelegate as home to all of your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `achievement_number` is 0 when starting the method, a SIGABRT will happen when this line is invoked:

`self.appDelegate.current_Achieved = [self.appDelegate.current_Achieved stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange((achievement_number-1), 1) withString:@"1"];`

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you have any suggested fix? Any insight is appreciated. Definitely value your opinion.

Comment: Yes just surround it with an "if" statement.  I can't really suggest an alternate piece of code without knowing how your code should function.  What should happen when `achievement_number` is 0?

Comment: Basically here's what the script is for: when a player accomplished an achievement while not connected to Game Center, then accomplished that same one while connected, the app wouldn't mark it as complete in Game Center. This is to check whether the accomplishment is in Game Center or not. If not, mark it off. Does that help?